# Jax-Rs Filter is not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, filter, jersey, jax-rs

I'm working on restful services and I need to validate the request using an authentication filter. My filter class method is not getting triggered when I'm calling the service.

I'm working on Jersey 2.--

**POM.xml**

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>    
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.13</jersey.version>
    </properties>
```

**web.xml**

```
  <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Sample Service</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>  
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
      <param-value>com.sample.filter,com.sample.api</param-value>  
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
              <param-name>javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
              <param-value>com.sample.filter.RestAuthenticationFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>  
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>  
        <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>   
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>
```

**RestAutheticationFilter class**

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class RestAuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
            throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("------------- Entering RestAuthenticationFilter -------------");
    }
}
```

I could not get `filter()` method triggered by above. I tried with annotations too as below.

**Interface**

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface Authenticated {}
```

**RestAuthenticationFilter class**

```
@Provider
@Authenticated
public class RestAuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
            throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("------------- Entering RestAuthenticationFilter -------------");
    }          
}
```

**web method**

```
   @GET
    @Authenticated
    @Path("{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value="Retrievs a single msg")
    @Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Message getMsg(
```

I have spent a lot time and could not figure yet what has gone wrong. Appreciate if anyone can find why the `filter()` method is not being triggered.

Comment: Is this `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilters` even a real property? Try replacing it with `jersey.config.server.provider.classnames`. Don't really see why it would be needed though. If the filter class is in the package listed in `jersey.config.server.provider.packages`, it should already be picked up by `@Provider`

Comment: Also (not related), but `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature` is useless. It a Jersey 2.x property. You can completely get rid of it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already tried with classnames property and it was not working.

Comment: Everything looks fine. I'm pretty positive that if I wanted to go through the steps of testing this (with what you have provided), it would work fine.

Comment: That is the reason I am confused too why it is not working. I tried changing the way you mentioned again and ran it. Still I do not get the S.O.P line in console. I also have other libraries and configuration which I have not given here. Can there be any conflicts because of that ?? but not related to filtering they are.

Comment: This is all I can tell to try. Change the dependency `jersey-container-servlet-core` to `jersey-container-servlet`. Comment out the entire web.xml. Create a `ResourceConfig` subclass. In the contructor call `packages("com.sample.api")` to register your resources and explicitly call `register(new RestAuthenticationFilter())` to register the filter.  Put a s.o.p inside the `ResourceConfig` constructor, see if it is created. And add `@ApplicationPath("/")` to the `ResourceConfig` subclass for the url mapping.

Comment: I followed the steps you mentioned and created a child class of ResourceConfig. I get the SOP lines printed in console as it is given before and after (new RestAuthenticationFilter()) . I'm not getting any error with the line (new()). I did not know about ResourceConfig class or what you really needed to test by that. So, Is there any way for me to proceed now with fixing this ??

Comment: This is another way to configure deployment (with no web.xml). Does the filter get called this way?

Comment: Since I did not know anything about this I just created this class in my api package and I made this child class instance in another method call. So I got the logs before and after. But, I'm unable to figure out how to call this when application is getting deployed to register the filter on container. Where should I put this class ? How should I use @ApplicationPath and register Filter class ? Thank you.

Comment: You don't ever need to instantiate the class yourself. The Jersey runtime will create it. The `@ApplicationPath` should be annotated above the `ResourceConfig` subclass. It serves the same purpose as `<url-mapping>` in the web.xml. The value you put in the annotation will be the servlet url mapping. See more [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.3)

Comment: where do I need to place this child class in my project structure ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Jersey will scan your packages looking for the ResourceConfig subclass with the annotation

Comment: Now I removed the new() statement I used to instantiate the sub class. After that I cannot see the SOP lines in console given inside constructor(Constructor of sub class has not run). I cant see the SOP line inside filter() method as well. Any idea what I can do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87388/discussion-between-peeskillet-and-nazneen).